# Difference in between HAS MANY and BELONGS TO in Yii framework

Tags: relational-theory, orm

I am new to the `Yii Framework`.

I discovered `HAS MANY` and `BELONGS TO` in the documentation, however I am confused about these features.

Can someone give some real life examples with a diagram that will clear up my doubts?

Comment: Where did you see "HAS MANY" and "BELONGS TO"? I don't see them day to day as DB Developer/DBA/Designer...

Comment: I have seen them in `php Yii Framework`.

Comment: then it's more of a php yii terminology than a general database term.

Comment: I have updated the question with php and Yii framework.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you've a blog every blog have some users and posts. Every post belongs to a user. So in that case you can create a relation on user BELONGS TO posts in yii framework.

relation in yii can be defined as :

```
'VarName'=>array('RelationType', 'ClassName', 'ForeignKey')
```

In case of post every post belongs to a user. So relation looks like this.

```
    public function relations() {
        return array(
            'user'=>array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'User', 'iduser'),    
        );
    }
```

Similarly, a user can have multiple posts. So relation for user as:

```
    public function relations() {
        return array(
            'posts'=>array(self::HAS_MANY, 'Post', 'iduser'),
        );
    }
```

For reference you can check [Working with relations in Yii Framework](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.arr)